# Java Regex Issues

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a character e.g. ' if it doesn't have the character \ before it.

Valid `État de l\'impression`

Invalid `État de l'impression`

Valid `Saisir l\'utilisateur et le domaine pour la connexion`

I believe what I am after is sort of assertion such as a negative lookbehind?

e.g. `(?<!\\)'` which works fine when I am testing in [RegexBuilder](http://renschler.net/RegexBuilder/)

However the problem is when  I am trying to make this work in Java

**Code**

```
String[] inputs = new String[] { "Recherche d'imprimantes en cours…", "Recherche  d\\'imprimantes en cours…" } ;

for(String input : inputs)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)'");
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(p.matcher(input).matches());
}
```

**Output**

```
Recherche d'imprimantes en cours…
false
Recherche  d\'imprimantes en cours…
false
```

Which should match `true`, `false`

Comment: might be simpler just to use "anything but this" `[^\\\\]` right before the '

Comment: @goldilocks, but that won't match if an (unescaped!) quote is at the start of the input string. In other words, `Pattern.compile("[^\\\\]'").matcher("'").find()` will return `false` while the quote doesn't have a backslash before it.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Silly me.  The negative lookbehind does works tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p.matcher(input).matches()` validates the entire input. Try `p.matcher(input).find()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Pattern.compile() on the same pattern in a loop -- it defeats the purpose of the "compile".

```
String[] inputs = new String[] { 
    "Recherche d'imprimantes en cours…", 
    "Recherche  d\\'imprimantes en cours…" 
};
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)'");

for (String s : inputs) {
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);
    while (mat.find()) {
        System.out.format("In \"%s\"\nFound: \"%s\" (%d, %d)\n",
            s, mat.group(), mat.start(), mat.end());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
In "Recherche d'imprimantes en cours…"
Found: "'" (11, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex should work fine, but `Matcher#matches()` doesn't work as you believe it does. It only returns true of the expression matches the *entire* string.

From the JavaDoc on `Matcher#matches()`:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.